# Error upgrading Symfony 3.2 to 3.3 - console.error_listener must be public as event subscribers are lazy-loaded

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.2

After upgrading Symfony from 3.2 to 3.3 i've got the following error right after composer update on the clearCache command:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: The service "console.error_listener" must be public as event subscribers are lazy-loaded.
```

I saw on `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/console.xml` that the service console.error_listener is set to `public="false"`.

Their [upgrade guide](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.3.md) doesn't say anything about it.

Stack trace:

```
#0 /www/acme/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php(143): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\DependencyInjection\RegisterListenersPass->process(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))
#1 /www/acme/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(736): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))
#2 /www/acme/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(560): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile()
#3 /www/acme/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(119): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->ini in /www/acme/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/DependencyInjection/RegisterListenersPass.php on line 91
```

composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "^3.3",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "kms/froala-editor-bundle": "dev-master",
    "stavarengo/php-sigep": "dev-master",
    "stavarengo/php-sigep-fpdf": "dev-master",
    "sendgrid/sendgrid": "~5.1",
    "symfony/event-dispatcher": "2.8",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
    "paquettg/php-html-parser": "^1.7",
    "mundipagg/mundipagg-one-php": "^1.4",
    "google/recaptcha": "~1.1",
    "doctrine/annotations": "^1.3",
    "signifyd/signifyd-php": "^0.2.0",
    "league/glide-symfony": "^1.0",
    "algolia/algolia-search-bundle": "^2.2",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8"
}
```

Comment: Try deleting the cache folder manually.

Comment: @ccKep, this was the first thing i tried.. didn't work..

Comment: The upgrade guide also says that *The cache:clear command should always be called with the --no-warmup option. Warmup should be done via the cache:warmup command.* - did you try that?

Comment: yes, im running `./bin/console c:c --no-warmup` which is also called automatically after composer update.. also tried `rm -rf var/cache/*`.. if i change public="true" it works, but i shouldn't do this.. this was the commit  which changed: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/0656284f7fe49418f3417d9f2a996be8ee540603

Comment: Can you add your `composer.json` to the question?

Comment: The code throwing that error should've been removed in [this commit](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/ecdf857b61402ea1c4d8d3841f2a58ca8984a554). Can you take a look at your `symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/DependencyInjection/RegisterListenersPass.php` ?

Comment: @ccKep hum.. the file is this `vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/DependencyInjection/RegisterListenersPass.php` which has in composer.json the following: `"symfony/event-dispatcher": "2.8"` Looks like i need to update this one and all others symfony/*

Comment: That shouldn't even have a separate entry in `composer.json` imho. [the symfony/symfony package](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/symfony) replaces that.

Comment: you're right! looks like this project was based on silex and still had this library there in composer. removing that solved the problem. thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `composer.json` had the following entry which was causing the problem:

```
"require": {
    ....
    "symfony/event-dispatcher": "2.8",
    ....
 }
```

Just removed and worked.
This line should not be there as symfony replaces it.